# Issue with Visual Studio Online OAuth unable to get access token

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, oauth

I am trying to query the REST api for Visual Studio Online and want to authorize my users via OAuth as described in this [msdn article](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started-auth-oauth2-vsi):

> Visual Studio Online uses the Oauth 2.0 protocol to authorize your app for a user and generate an access token. Use this token when you call the REST APIs from your app.

I am using JavaScript to try to achieve this as follows (onload function omitted for brevity and code/clientSecret seem to be set to the correct values):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params =  'client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer' +
'&client_assertion={' + clientSecret + '}' +
'&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' +
'&assertion={' + code +'}' +
'&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri);
xhr.open('POST','https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = //onloadfunction
xhr.send(params);
```

Yet I keep getting the following response:

> POST https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token 400 (Bad Request) 
>   {"Error":"invalid_client","ErrorDescription":"Invalid client auth token."}

I am sure I am missing something simple here. I have tried a variety of combinations but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the curly braces { } around the client assertion and assertion values.

Also, in general, you shouldn't be using this form of OAuth to authorize users in a JavaScript-based app (since you have no way to secure your app's client secret).